# Combining disparate sql queries in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, union

I have a table, tableA, with 3 rows and 2 columns of data that I need using specific criteria.
I have another table, tableB, with 1 row and 3 columns of data that I need using specific criteria.
The tables have nothing in common, no joins, etc.

I want the following result set returned:

> t=table, r=row, c= column

```
tAr1c1,tAr1c2,tBr1c1,tBr1c2,tBr1c3
tAr2c1,tAr2c2,tBr1c1,tBr1c2,tBr1c3
tAr3c1,tAr3c2,tBr1c1,tBr1c2,tBr1c3
```

I investigated union, but that is not it. Is this more a stored procedure than a sql statement? Almost Cartesian product?

Comment: Nothing almost about it; this is a Cartesian product.  All records from A combined with all records from B.  3*1.  `Select A.*, B.* FROM tableA ACROSS JOIN tableB B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no relationship between the two tables, you have to use a `cross join`

```
select  *
from    table1
cross join
        table2
```